# Sales don't work in Magento Reports

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9

I have a strange behaviour in Magento Reports>Sales. It doesn't matter which report I select and which dates I set, it shows no data found except for 4 days worth of orders; I searched the web for the problem, but it doesn't look like anyone else has had the same problem before.

What I tried:

1. Update statistics.
2. Change timezones and set first day of a week to Monday intead of Sunday.

Nothing worked.

The data is there because in the dashboard it all shows up correctly, but I need the reports section to work for more detailed reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer myself! :)

I just noticed a little drop down in the Reports>Refresh Statistics page, by default it is set up to refresh statistics of current day, I set it to lifetime statistics and it all works now!